# React hook form - appending to array field updates values, but not fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have made a small codesandbox with reproducible bug [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-pond-dd7brq?file=/src/ArrayField.tsx).
I have a form component where I am setting useForm hook with initial values. Form has an `IncomeInfo` and a component with array field as child components:

```
const { pageFormValues, setPageFormValues, setActiveStep } = usePageProvider();
const initialValues = pageFormValues ?? createInitialValues(income);
const [action, setAction] = useState<ActionStatus>(ActionStatus.IDLE);

const useFormMethods = useForm({
        defaultValues: initialValues,
});


return (
    <FormProvider {...useFormMethods}>
        <form onSubmit={useFormMethods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
           <IncomeInfo />
           <IncomeBaseTable initialValues={initialValues} />
```

`IncomeBaseTable` looks like this:

```
export const IncomeBaseTable = ({ initialValues }) => (
    <TableWrapper heading={["Period", "Employer", "Total", ""]}>
        <ArrayField
            name="incomeBase"
            children={({ index, handleRemove, handleAppend }) => (
                <TableRowWrapper
                    cells={[
                        <div className="flex gap-x-4">
                            <FormControlledDatePicker
                                key={`incomeBase[${index}].from`}
                                name={`incomeBase[${index}].from`}
                                label="From"
                                placeholder="DD.MM.ÅÅÅÅ"
                                defaultValue={initialValues.incomeBase[index].from}
                                hideLabel
                            />
                            <FormControlledDatePicker
                                key={`incomeBase[${index}].to`}
                                name={`incomeBase[${index}].to`}
                                label="To"
                                placeholder="DD.MM.ÅÅÅÅ"
                                defaultValue={initialValues.incomeBase[index].to}
                                hideLabel
                            />
                        </div>,
                        <FormControlledTextField
                            key={`incomeBase[${index}].employer`}
                            name={`incomeBase[${index}].employer`}
                            label="Employer"
                            hideLabel
                        />,
                        <FormControlledTextField
                            key={`incomeBase[${index}].total`}
                            name={`incomeBase[${index}].total`}
                            label="Total"
                            type="number"
                            hideLabel
                        />,
                        <Button
                            key={`delete-button-${index}`}
                            onClick={() => handleRemove(index)}
                            icon={<Delete aria-hidden />}
                            variant="tertiary"
                            size="xsmall"
                        />,
                    ]}
                />
            )}
        />
    </TableWrapper>
);
```

`TableWrapper` looks like this:

```
export const TableWrapper = ({ heading, children }: { heading: string[]; children: ReactNode }) => (
    <Table size="small">
        <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
                {heading.map((header) => (
                    <Table.HeaderCell scope="col" key={header}>
                        {header}
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                ))}
            </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>
        <Table.Body>{children}</Table.Body>
    </Table>
);

export const TableRowWrapper = ({ cells }: { cells: ReactElement[] }) => (
    <Table.Row>
        {cells.map((cell, index) => {
            if (!index)
                return (
                    <Table.HeaderCell scope="row" key={cell.key}>
                        {cell}
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                );
            return <Table.DataCell key={index}>{cell}</Table.DataCell>;
        })}
    </Table.Row>
);
```

When I am appending from `IncomeInfo` to the field array like this, values get updated, but fields are the same as they were before the append action:

```
const { control, getValues } = useFormContext();
const { append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "incomeBase",
});

const handleOnChange = (checked, incomeValues) => {
    if (checked) {
        append({
            from: null,
            to: null,
            employer: "",
            total: incomeValues.sum,
        });
    }
};
```

When I am logging in the `ArrayFields` component I can see that I get new values with `getValues` method, but `fields` are not updated:

```
const ArrayFields = ({ name, children }: ArrayFieldsProps) => {
    const { control, getValues } = useFormContext();
    const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: name,
    });

    const handleAppend = (value) => {
        append(value);
        console.log("add: ", getValues());
    };

    const handleRemove = (index) => {
        remove(index);
        console.log("remove: ", getValues());
    };

    console.log("field", fields);
    console.log("value", getValues().incomeBase);
```

Since fields are not updated the new field is not rendered. Why are values updated, but not fields?

If I append to the array field from `IncomeBaseTable` component, then it appends and rerenders with new fields:

```
export const IncomeBaseTable = ({ initialValues }) => (
    <TableWrapper heading={["Period", "Employer", "Total", ""]}>
        <ArrayField
            name="incomeBase"
            children={({ index, handleRemove, handleAppend }) => (
                <TableRowWrapper
                    cells={[
                        <div className="flex gap-x-4">
                            <FormControlledDatePicker
                                key={`incomeBase[${index}].from`}
                                name={`incomeBase[${index}].from`}
                                label="From"
                                placeholder="DD.MM.ÅÅÅÅ"
                                defaultValue={initialValues.incomeBase[index].from}
                                hideLabel
                            />
                            <FormControlledDatePicker
                                key={`incomeBase[${index}].to`}
                                name={`incomeBase[${index}].to`}
                                label="To"
                                placeholder="DD.MM.ÅÅÅÅ"
                                defaultValue={initialValues.incomeBase[index].to}
                                hideLabel
                            />
                        </div>,
                        <FormControlledTextField
                            key={`incomeBase[${index}].employer`}
                            name={`incomeBase[${index}].employer`}
                            label="Employer"
                            hideLabel
                        />,
                        <FormControlledTextField
                            key={`incomeBase[${index}].total`}
                            name={`incomeBase[${index}].total`}
                            label="Total"
                            type="number"
                            hideLabel
                        />,
                        <Button
                            key={`add-button-${index}`}
                            onClick={() => handleAppend(fieldInitialValues)}
                            icon={<Add aria-hidden />}
                            variant="tertiary"
                            size="xsmall"
                        />,
                    ]}
                />
            )}
        />
    </TableWrapper>
);
```

Why is it adding to field array and rerendering when I append from the `IncomeBaseTable`, but not when I append from `IncomeInfo` component?

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it to work by using one instance of the `useArrayField` in the parent component and then passing it as a prop to child components. It won't work when I have more instances with same field name. Not sure why is that, beats the purpose of being a hook if I need to pass it around as a prop.

Comment: Can you explain in simple words what is the issue you are facing? I tried reading it but still don't quite understand and what should happen, the sandbox I used has a error in it and there is a code difference between here and the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

`react-hook-form` uses [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) under the hood to reduce the number of renders. In your case, you update fields outside of the hook `useArrayField`. This hook have his own way to detect changes and are not expecting external changes.

You could forward `useArrayField` values to `<IncomeInfo/>` or use [`useWatch()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch/) to get the fields values.

**EDIT:** There is a good example in the last section of the doc (**Controlled Field Array**) : https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/

Comment: ArrayField is my component it has nothing to do with hook-form, in both places component I ```useArrayField```. I have updated my question with a codesandbox where you can reproduce the bug.

Comment: my bad for the confusion. I updated my answer but I think it still apply as you're updating fields collection externally.

Comment: You can check out codesandox that I added, you can see there.

Comment: Looks like I need to use the same instance of ```useArrayField```, it won't work when I have more instances with same name. Not sure why is that, beats the purpose of being a hook if I need to pass around it as a prop.

Comment: I forked your sandbox and removed ArrayField component (just to remove the useArrayField hook) and now it's working. If you want to keep that wrapper, you need to provide the hook method like you did with other components. https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-shaw-p5wub5?file=/src/IncomeInfo.tsx

edit: there is still minor things to fix on the example but you get the picture

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, I feel it is a bit annoying that I can't call hook from several places in the code, but I need to pass it as a prop.

Comment: I understand what you mean but it's really about performance in this case. You can still watch field and control the array (like the example I provided in the link above). This what I would personally do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting the `fields` or `updated fields` from `useFormContext` itself so that you can access the `form context` or `updated fields`.

Here is `IncomeInfo` where you will append fields

```
import { useFieldArray, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import { v1 as uuid} from "uuid";
export const IncomeInfo = ({ fieldArrayMethods }) => {
  const { getValues,control } = useFormContext();
  const { append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "incomeBase"
  });

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    append({
      from: "",
      to: "",
      employer: "",
      total: "",
      id: uuid()
    });
  };
  console.log("append: ", getValues());

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => handleOnClick()}>
      add from outside
    </button>
  );
};
```

Get the `fields` in `IncomeBaseTable` with the help of `getValues()` overloaded menthod , specifically `getValues(name?: name)`.

```
import { TableWrapper, TableRowWrapper } from "./TableWrapper";
import { Button } from "@navikt/ds-react";
import ArrayFields from "./ArrayField";
import { FormControlledTextField } from "./FormControlledTextField";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export const IncomeBaseTable = ({ initialValues, fieldArrayMethods }) => {
  const {getValues} = useFormContext();
  const incomeBaseFields = getValues("incomeBase");

  console.log("updated/initial fields",incomeBaseFields)
  return(
    <TableWrapper heading={["From", "To", "Employer", "Total", ""]}>
      <ArrayFields
        name="incomeBase"
        fields={incomeBaseFields}
        children={({ index }) => (
          <TableRowWrapper
            cells={[
              <FormControlledTextField
                key={`incomeBase[${index}].from`}
                name={`incomeBase[${index}].from`}
              />,
              <FormControlledTextField
                key={`incomeBase[${index}].to`}
                name={`incomeBase[${index}].to`}
              />,
              <FormControlledTextField
                key={`incomeBase[${index}].employer`}
                name={`incomeBase[${index}].employer`}
              />,
              <FormControlledTextField
                key={`incomeBase[${index}].total`}
                name={`incomeBase[${index}].total`}
              />,
              <Button
                key={`add-button-${index}`}
                type="button"
                onClick={() =>
                  fieldArrayMethods.append({
                    from: null,
                    to: null,
                    employer: "",
                    total: 123213
                  })
                }
                variant="tertiary"
                size="xsmall"
              >
                Add from inside
              </Button>
            ]}
          />
        )}
      />
    </TableWrapper>
  );
}
```

[Check the fix here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-moon-px3qeu?file=/src/IncomeBaseTable.tsx)